# Insert XML into SQL Table XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Am trying to insert XML into XML Column.. getting following error: .

Msg 6819, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.

My SQL query

```
declare @tempTable Table (xmlValue xml)
insert into @tempTable
select EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary from Employee2
for xml path('EmployeeDetails')
```

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the error says, you can't use `FOR XML` in the body of an `INSERT` statement.  You have to wrap the part that retrieves the XML:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    xmlValue xml
)

INSERT @tempTable (xmlValue)
SELECT
(
    SELECT EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary
    FROM Employee2
    FOR XML PATH('EmployeeDetails')
)
```